# How to see version and uptime of running FreeRadius daemon

Tags: debian, freeradius

I have a FreeRadius server doing authentication for my 802.1X infra-structure, in a Debian 9.1.

How can I see what is the version and uptime of the running FreeRadius daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For seeing the software version, *if installed with a deb package*, with dpkg:

```
$ dpkg -l freeradius
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                        Version                    Architecture               Description
+++-===========================================-==========================-==========================-===========================================================================================
ii  freeradius                                  3.0.16+git                 amd64                      high-performance and highly configurable RADIUS server
```

Also from the command line, you can do:

```
$freeradius -v
radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16 (git #0bd5a4cec), for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Jul 17 2017 at 16:00:00
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
```

With the debug tool `radmin` from FreeRadius, you can see both the version and uptime of the service:

```
radius2:~$ sudo radmin
radmin version 3.0.16 (git #0bd5a4cec), built on Jul 17 2017 at 16:00:00 - FreeRADIUS Server administration tool.
Copyright (C) 2008-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License v2.
radmin> show version
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16 (git #0bd5a4cec), for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Jul 17 2017 at 16:00:00
radmin> show uptime
Up since Mon Jul 24 14:39:51 2017
radmin> exit
```

For `radmin` to work correctly, as @Arran correctly points out, you ought to have configured the `control-socket` functionality.

You do that with:

```
ln -s sites-available/control-socket sites-enabled/control-socket
```

Comment: Remember to link in the command socket (sites-available/control-socket -> sites-enabled/control-socket)